# Android. Запуск таймера из другого класса на MainActivity. Как? Пример кода

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь выводить таймер обратного отчёта из основного класса, но выдаёт ошибку.
Класс таймера Timer.java:

```
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.Random;

public class Timer extends Thread {
    final Random random = new Random();
    private long timer_ot_do = random.nextInt(7000) + 3000;
    private String timer_fact;

    public void run()
    {
        new CountDownTimer(timer_ot_do, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                timer_fact = "Ожидайте: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000;
                Log.e("Таймер в работе - ",timer_fact);
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                timer_fact = "Готово";
            }

        }.start();
    }

    public void start()
    {
        this.start();
    }

    public String timer_rezult()
    {
        return timer_fact;
    }

}
```

Из MainActivity вызываю следующим способом:

```
TextView timer_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView11);
Timer_rezult = new Timer();
Timer_rezult.start();
timer_text.setText(Timer_rezult.timer_rezult());
```

Выдаёт ошибку при запуску - java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB.
Ошибка происходит на " this.start();". Однако если закоментировать эту функцию и запустить сразу run из главной активити, то в лог таймер работает корректно, но в текствью не передаётся на главную активити. Как сделать чтобы таймер передавался? Спасибо.

Comment: Насколько я помню изменять данные View можно только в Ui Thread, поэтому в активности создаем метод runOnUiThread(TimerTick); , где TimerTick - это Runnable а в нем уже и меняем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас получается зацикливание, Вы вызываете метод, который внутри вызывает себя же.

```
public void start(){ 
    this.start(); //Ошибка тут. вызывается метод, тот что на строчку выше и так пока есть память
}
```

Как минимум назовите метод не start а startTimer - что бы было меньше путаницы. 
Зачем таймер делать Тредом?

Попробуйте как-то так:

```
public class Timer {

private CountDownTimer currentTimer;

public Timer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval, ITimerCallback callback) {

    currentTimer = new CountDownTimer(millisInFuture, countDownInterval) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            long time = millisUntilFinished / 1000;
            callback.ontTimerNewValue(String.valueOf(time));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            callback.ontTimerNewValue("Готово");
        }
    }.start();
}

public void onTimerCancel() { //Отмена если надо
    currentTimer.cancel();
}

public interface ITimerCallback {

    void ontTimerNewValue(String value);

}
}
```

Запуск так

```
void timerStart() {

    new Timer(10000, 1000, new Timer.ITimerCallback() {
        @Override
        public void ontTimerNewValue(String value) {
            timer_text.setText(value);
        }
    });

}
```